# How to check accessibility enabled or disabled and then change the view accordingly in android?

Tags: android, accessibility

I am working on android application development. We need to do some changes as per accessibility guidelines i.e our app should support accessibility guidelines also. So my question is how we will make the code change as per the Accessibility guidelines.

For example: In my Login screen, as per the accessibility guideline, the textview should be 48dp in size. But this change should happen only when the user enables accessibility in the device. Otherwise, the default size of the textview should be 40dp. How to achieve this in my app? Could anyone please help me on this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

This is an extension function that checks if a particular `AccessibiltyService` is running

```
fun Context.isAccessibilityServiceRunning(): Boolean {
    val accessibilityManager =
        getSystemService(Context.ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE) as AccessibilityManager

    return accessibilityManager
        .getEnabledAccessibilityServiceList(AccessibilityEvent.TYPES_ALL_MASK)
        .map { it.id }
        .contains(ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE_ID)
}
```

There are various accessibility services. If you were checking for any of them to be running you could just check to see if the service list is no empty.

I don't see any accessibility resource qualifiers here:

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources#AlternativeResources

Because of that you will probably need to programmatically change the size or create a style that you apply.

Comment: Hi, thank you. Gone through the link you provided and tried the given sample code. This is helpful. Could you provide a sample for one textview with accessibility and without accessibility and can you show how it works?

Comment: Who is ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE_ID in this context?